# Emscripten OpenGL (3) gives versions errors

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, webgl2

OS X - Chrome.

Im new to OpenGL / emscripten and trying to setup a simple script that uses WebGL 2, OpenGL 3+ and gets build through emscripten into webassembly.

Compiling of WebGL 1 / OpenGL 2 worked without a problem. And setting the canvas to WebGL 2 / OpenGL 3 also seems to work. When I check the current version that is running,  it informs me about OpenGL 3.0 and WebGL2 (but maybe its not using it..?).

But, emcc still screams errors about the shader im giving being only compatible from version 3.0+ and thus implying im running openGL 1/2 ?

*Setting a new context through emscripten*

```
EmscriptenWebGLContextAttributes ctxAttrs;
emscripten_webgl_init_context_attributes(&ctxAttrs);
ctxAttrs.alpha = GL_TRUE;
ctxAttrs.depth = GL_TRUE;
ctxAttrs.stencil = GL_TRUE;
ctxAttrs.antialias = 4;
ctxAttrs.premultipliedAlpha = false;
ctxAttrs.preserveDrawingBuffer = false;
ctxAttrs.minorVersion = 0;
ctxAttrs.majorVersion = 2; // WebGL2

this->context = emscripten_webgl_create_context(0, &ctxAttrs);
assert(this->context > 0); // Must have received a valid context.
int res = emscripten_webgl_make_context_current(this->context);
assert(res == EMSCRIPTEN_RESULT_SUCCESS);
assert(emscripten_webgl_get_current_context() == this->context);
```

*Shaders* :

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 300 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
        "}\0";

const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 300 core\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
        "}\n\0";
```

When I do a log of the current OpenGL version right after the creation of the context,

```
printf("OpenGL version supported by this platform : %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

I get this :

> OpenGL version supported by this platformOpenGL ES 3.0 (WebGL 2.0
>   (OpenGL ES 3.0 Chromium))

Chrome console says this

```
ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILEDERROR: 0:1: 'core' : invalid version directive
00:53:19.828 index.js:1 ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error
00:53:19.829 index.js:1
00:53:19.830 index.js:1 ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILEDERROR: 0:1: 'core' : invalid version directive
00:53:19.831 index.js:1 ERROR: 0:2: 'out' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
00:53:19.832 index.js:1 ERROR: 0:2: '' : No precision specified for (float)
00:53:19.833 index.js:1 ERROR: 0:5: '1.0f' : Floating-point suffix unsupported prior to GLSL ES 3.00
00:53:19.834 index.js:1 ERROR: 0:5: '1.0f' : syntax error
00:53:19.835
```

I call emscripten like this, with FULL_ES3 and WEBGL2 enabled.

```
emcc src/main.cpp src/lib/Chart.cpp -s SAFE_HEAP=1 --bind  -s WASM=1 -O3 -o index.js -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=0  -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0 --pre-js pre-module.js --post-js post-module.js -s GL_ASSERTIONS=1 -s INVOKE_RUN=0  -std=c++11 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s USE_GLFW=3 -s OFFSCREENCANVAS_SUPPORT=1
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>`#version 300 core` is for OpenGL 3.</s>  WebGL does not support this.

`#version 300 es` is for OpenGL ES 3.  This is what you want.

Comment: That's... almost right. There actually *is no* 3.00 desktop GLSL version. The GLSL version that corresponds with desktop OpenGL 3.0 is 1.30. But you are correct that `300 core` should never work.

Comment: Right OpenGL 3.3 is when it started that style of GLSL versioning.  Good catch.

Comment: Well damn... Just woke up to give it another try after I spent almost 24 hours yesterday finding the problem. And nowhere it stood out, thanks guys!!!!!! Just a quick side-question.. There seems to be a lot of OpenGL documentation / tutorials about v1/2 and v3.3+ (cause a lot stuff changed after 3.3).. I guess I cannot write 3.3 openGL with WebGL2 cause its bound to OpenGL 3.0, correct? Cause it feels like im writing 'almost useless' code with v3.0, since everything from 3.3 is different

Comment: btw, I assume from the answers #version 300 es is the way to go?? (Doesn't give any errors anymore so guess its 'official' path)

Comment: WebGL3 is based on OpenGL ES 3.0. Not OpenGL 3.0 Do not confuse OpenGL ES with desktop OpenGL. They are not the same thing. OpenGL ES are what run on mobile devices. On desktop the browser emulates them, on Windows using DirectX, on Mac and Linix using OpenGL at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add my solution was to modify the emscripten library as such

1. copy `emscripten/src/library_gl.js` into your project
2. edit your copy and add these lines to the end of `getSource`

   ```
     getSource: function(shader, count, string, length) {

       ...

       const isFragmentShader = GLctx.getShaderParameter(GL.shaders[shader], 0x8B4F /* GL_SHADER_TYPE */) === 0x8B30 /* GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER */;
       const header = isFragmentShader ? "#version 300 es\nprecision mediump float;\n" : "#version 300 es\n";
       source = source.replace(/#version.*?\n/, header);

       return source;
     },
   ```
3. compile my code with something like

   ```
   emcc -std=c++11 -s WASM=1 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 --js-library library_gl.js myprogram.cpp
   ```

Basically search and replace parts of GLSL into GLSL ES. That way I don't have to modify the shaders, depending on the shader.

Also, if your C++ is not printing out shader complilation and link errors you can add them in from JavaScript like this.

Before you include your emscripten code include this script

```
WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.compileShader = (function(origFn) {
   return function(shader) {
      origFn.call(this, shader);
      const status = this.getShaderParameter(shader, this.COMPILE_STATUS);
      if (!status) {
        console.error(this.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      }
   };
}(WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.compileShader));

WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.linkProgram = (function(origFn) {
   return function(program) {
      origFn.call(this, program);
      const status = this.getProgramParameter(program, this.LINK_STATUS);
      if (!status) {
        console.error(this.getProgramInfoLog(program));
      }
   };
}(WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.compileShader));
```

This will print compilation errors to the JavaScript console and would have shown the error

Example:

```js
WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.compileShader = (function(origFn) {
   return function(shader) {
      origFn.call(this, shader);
      const status = this.getShaderParameter(shader, this.COMPILE_STATUS);
      if (!status) {
        console.error(this.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      }
   };
}(WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.compileShader));

WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.linkProgram = (function(origFn) {
   return function(program) {
      origFn.call(this, program);
      const status = this.getProgramParameter(program, this.LINK_STATUS);
      if (!status) {
        console.error(this.getProgramInfoLog(program));
      }
   };
}(WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.compileShader));

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    alert("need webgl2");
    return;
  }
  
  const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vs, `#version 300 core
    void main() {
      gl_Position = vec4(0);
    }
  `);
  gl.compileShader(vs);
}
main();
```

When I run the code above I get

```
ERROR: 0:1: 'core' : invalid version directive
```